# Active nav-item highlighting based on pk passed in url

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 4 nav-items being generating dynamically based on the Django Model entries.

My template code is as below:

```
{% for stockbroker in stockbrokers %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'broker:display_stocks' stockbroker.id %}" id="nav">{{ stockbroker.broker_name }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to highlight the currently active nav based on the id I am passing in the url section of the a tag href. Is it possible to achieve this?

I am generating these nav links in the base.html using context_processors.py

```
from .models import StockBroker


def stockbrokers(request):
    return {'stockbrokers': StockBroker.objects.all()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if condition should work for this:

```
{% for stockbroker in stockbrokers %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {% if stockbroker.id == current_id %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'broker:display_stocks' stockbroker.id %}" id="nav">{{ stockbroker.broker_name }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: `current_id` (or variable name of your preference) should be passed in the context.
The context is the dictionary that is passed while rendering the template, example:

```
def my_view(request):
    # View Code
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'current_id': current_id})
```

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please elaborate on current_id (or variable name of your preference) should be passed in the context. I am not clear how and where exactly I need to do this.

Comment: I am doing this in my base.html using context_processors.py. Will passing the context from the child pages help in highlighting the nav in base.html?

Comment: Just tried it and its working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @codecrazy46 Context processors work for all templates, i.e. you can use them to easily add something to all templates. But it would be very confusing to use them for variables that need to be passed on a view basis, i.e some view might or might not have some data. It's better to pass the context for those. (Your context processor would still work properly)